# Database query vs store in table

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

I have a few models.

Game:

- pk: id
- ...other

GameSession (Manyto1 with game):

- pk: id
- game: game_id
- ...other

ChatSession (1to1 with GameSession):

- pk: id
- session: game_session_id
- ...other

Would it be better to store the information in multiple models, or query for the correct object?

Aka

To get the chat session for a given game session, should I query something like `select * from chatsessions where session=INT` or should I store the `chatsession` id in the GameSession model so it doesn't have to query every time it needs to access the chat session?

Comment: By "model" you mean table?

Comment: @stickybit yea each model is stored in its own table. (Using Django)

Comment: Ah OK, model like in ORM model... missed that, sorry.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What would be the benefit of storing `chatsession_id` in the `GameSession` model? You will run a query for the rest of the information anyways and it doesn't matter whether you specify `pk` or `game_session_id` in your `WHERE` clause. However, it is a valid question if you are asking whether or not to merge those two models into one.

Answer (score 0):

If the chat is 1:1 with the gamesession, then it will depend on your use cases. If you always need to read the two together then there is probably no good reason to split it up.

If on the other hand the chat session is a really wide table and is only references sometimes, then better to keep it separate.

Realistically the impact of accessing two separate tables is not going to be great, but if its two tables you will have two sets of indexes, plus the concern of maintaining referential integrity between the two.

So without any more information I'd guess they are better off together.